# Short story with a man who keeps passing out due to his starched collar poking his neck

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

Weird isolated memory, but I was recently at our church, and when I turned my head, the collar put pressure on the side of my neck, which suddenly reminded me of a short story I read, probably in the late 1980s to early 1990s, where a plot point was the characters finding out that a certain young man kept passing out due to his starched collar pressing into the side of his neck, and therefore his carotid artery. I want to say that it was a mystery of some sort, where the twist basically came into that he either thought he was being assaulted, or he was in a situation where someone took a swing at him, and his short collar made him drop unconscious before the punch could even hit him. Because of the plot point of starched collars (and much of my mystery readings at the time being from the shelves of my parents), I suspect it's an older story, probably part of a collection centered under a particular detective.